# Peut-on « réguler davantage les armes à feu » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, faux-amis

> Joe Biden a estimé mercredi, dix ans après la tuerie dans l’école de
> Sandy Hook, que les États-Unis avaient une « obligation morale » de
> **réguler** davantage les armes à feu, et qu’elle devrait se « sentir coupable » de ne pas l’avoir fait. (*AFP* via [*LaPresse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/2022-12-14/obligation-morale-de-reguler-davantage-les-armes-a-feu-dit-biden.php), je souligne.)

[*Réguler*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R1376) signifie « assurer la régulation [...] » (Ac.9), et [*régulation*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R1374) dispose d'une extension de sens :

> Contrôle d’une activité, d’un système complexe visant à s’assurer de
> leur bon fonctionnement, à orienter leur évolution (dans cet emploi,
> la *régulation* s’oppose à la *règlementation*, qui est générale,
> préalable, impersonnelle et permanente). (Ac.9)

L'emploi de *réguler* dans le texte cité est-il conforme à cette extension et le cas échéant en quoi le sens du propos différerait en contexte du sens qu'il aurait avec le verbe *réglementer* ?

Comment: *Réguler* a pour origine *diriger*. On dirige par la Loi qui, édictant les règles à appliquer au travers d'un *règlement*, donne le *cadre statique* de l'action sans savoir comment va évoluer cette dernière. Ensuite, on dirige par la Justice qui contrôle *l'application dynamique* de la Loi et permet la *régulation*, les “ajustements” de la Loi par avenants, ou par évolutions du Code de procédure issu du règlement.

Comment: *Édicter* contient la notion de *promulguer* un texte juridique, *stipuler* celle *d'énoncer* une condition : on peut stipuler avant d'édicter, ou après, mais pas pendant.

Answer (score 1):

C'est un anglicisme à cause de l'anglais "regulate" dans les textes traduits de l'anglais américain (généralement par l'agence et non par La Presse). Quand il s'agit des lois canadiennes, *La Presse* utilise plutôt les termes *réglementer* ou *contrôler*.

Comment: Possiblement mais la question demeure, peut-on employer _réguler_ dans ce contexte-là ?

Comment: Je dirait que non. Ce n'est pas un emprunt naturel ou utile (contrairement à, disons *nominer*) et il n'est pas vraiment intégré dans le français en dehors de ces traductions boiteuses.

Answer (score 1):

Non, il n'est pas conforme, à mon avis.

Il n'est pas inutile de s'attarder sur ce quoi porte le verbe « réguler » ; dans le texte examiné c'est le nom  « arme à feu », mais ce nom n'est qu'une vague référence à tout autre chose, qui concerne les armes à feu, et qui en dehors d'un contexte précis, celui du texte examiné, par exemple, n'est pas identifiable. Ce n'est même pas identifiable précisément dans ce contexte précis puisqu'on ne sait pas s'il s'agit de la vente d'armes à feu au public, de la possession d'armes à feu par le public, ou bien des deux.

S'il ne s'agit que de traiter le problème en agissant sur les possibilités de possession, il n'y a rien qui puisse être appelé une activité, et donc « réglementer » est le verbe qui convient. Si c'est en agissant sur la vente, il est bien question d'une activité ; cependant,  l'évolution de la vente en tant que moyen de faire des gains n'est pas un concernement : les mesures visent à établir des normes restrictives indépendantes de toute fluctuation des marchés, de toutes évolution sociale sur un terme plus ou moins long ; ce sont des mesure permanentes dont l'effet ne dépend   pas de fluctuations ou de changements dans le système de vente. Ces mesures ne peuvent pas être comprises comme portant sur le fonctionnement de la vente ; c'est sur les conséquences négatives de la vente qu'elles portent, ce qui signifie  pas la vente en soi, mais en tant que service rendu, à l'individu ou à la société. En conclusion, on doit parler de la réglementation de la vente. Il s'agit probablement des deux domaines, la vente et la possession, des domaines  qui concernent la loi de près ;  évidemment, « règlementer les armes à feu » est le terme qui convient, si on le tolère en tant que représentant d'un terme, lui, syntaxiquement correct et explicite, c'est à dire « règlementer la vente des armes à feu au public et de leur possession par le public ».

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî J'ai utilisé ce mot parce qu'il est attesté dans le TLFi (Rem. On rencontre ds la docum. le subst. masc. _concernement_. Fait d'être concerné. Le concernement de la première personne et le contenu de la responsabilité métempirique forment un seul problème (Jankélévitch, Le Je-ne-sais-quoi et le presque-rien, 1957, p. 219).) En quoi le trouvez-vous inacceptable ?

Comment: Mon opinion est la suivante : quand on écrit pour d'autres, on veut leur faciliter la tâche, on veut qu'ils lisent tout d'un trait, pas qu'ils achoppent sur des phrases lourdes ou des termes inusités qui leur font douter d'un calque de l'anglais. Il s'agit d'une forme de civisme je dirais. Aussi, ça détourne l'attention d'un propos qui par ailleurs peut-être valable. Veut-on forcer le lecteur à consulter un dictionnaire ? Le terme juste n'a pas besoin d'être inusité. Regarde ceci : https://www.cairn.info/revue-natures-sciences-societes-2008-4-page-317.htm Faisais-tu appel à cette notion ?

Comment: À toi de voir...

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî [Concernement](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concernement): (Psychiatrie) *Seuil d’entrée dans la schizophrénie, marqué par un délire explicatif.* Le terme est peut-être le bon ici.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Veut-on faire profiter le lecteur de termes nouveaux qui augmentent son vocabulaire ? Oui. J'ai moi même à vérifier en permanence des termes nouveaux  et je ne le fais jamais avec mauvaise volonté mais plutôt avec de la curiosité.  // Je dois dire que dans le mot « préoccupation » les connotations qui touchent à l'idée de souci  ne me semblent pas très appropriées dans ce contexte où je préfère un terme plus factuel ; c'est un mot, qui est cependant acceptable, alors je le laisse.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi appliquer la définition qui n'est évidemment pas celle qui convient ? Celle du TLFi correspond bien, il me semble.

Comment: @jlliagre — La source de la référence philosophique, son miroir psychiatrique et la conclusion attendue est savoureuse. Le référant, le référé et les références réalisent la perfection du Un illusoire.

Comment: Juste las... ..

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî … dans l'histoire du site, vous n'êtes pas le seul.